# Customizing tick marks and labels on x-axis (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm drawing a graph in Microsoft Excel and I'm just wondering if this is possible, and if it is, how to achieve it. I've attached an illustration below:

1. This is what I have >
   [regular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdiIc.png)
2. This is what I'm trying to do > (I did this in Paint to illustrate)
   [edited in paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NU4fe.png)

Can the y-axis to cross over the x-axis at 30, but the tick marks starts at 100 onwards? I also don't want any labeling or tick marks below 30.

Thank you.

Comment: I'd like to comment on the 3 bullet points. I know how to do those individually as they are simple chart formatting. I just don't know if it's possible to do all three on 1 single chart, and this is the problem I'm getting.

Comment: All three of those items are independent, so yes you can do all three on one chart.

Comment: @TimWilliams - How? If you start the axis at 30 and want tick spacing of 100, Excel only allows ticks at increments of 100 starting at 30, that is 30, 130, 230, etc. The workaround would be to hide the default tick marks and labels, then plot another series with Y=0 and X=30, 100, 200, 300, etc. Use a plus-sign marker to simulate a tick mark, and add data labels below these points showing the X values.

Comment: @JonPeltier - I agree I did not fully meet the OP's expectations, since I was more focused on the tick labels than the ticks themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hide the default axis and build your own. In my example, I want the axis to start at 30 and end at 730, but have tick marks and labels at 100, 200, 300, etc.

I set up a data range with X values in one column of 100, 200, 300, ... 700, and Y values of zero in the next column.

Chart 1 is the original chart without anything added or removed. Chart 2 has the added series, shown as orange plus-sign markers. Chart 3 has data labels below these added points, showing the default Y values of zero (orange text). In Chart 4 I have formatted the labels so that they show the X values instead of the Y values. In Chart 5 I have changed the X axis scale so it starts at 30 and ends at 730. I have also hidden the axis labels, not by removing them, but my using a custom number format of "  ", which preserves the margin below the axis to leave room for my custom data labels. Finally in Chart 6 I have formatted the plus sign markers to match the axis line and the data labels to match the other chart text. I have also formatted the Y axis with major tick marks that cross the axis.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First two are basic chart formatting - plenty of examples to be found via Google for those.

For the third one you can use a custom format for your axis labels. See for example:

http://www.officetooltips.com/excel_2016/tips/conditional_formatting_of_chart_axes.html

Your format could look something like this:

```
 [White][<=30]General;[Black][>30]General
```

In VBA:

```
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlCategory)
    .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "[White][<=30]General;[Black][>30]General"
End With
```

Comment: Yes, the first two are basic chart formatting By Itself. The part I don't understand is having the chart cross over the x-axis at 30 AND show tick marks and labeling starting at 50 for every 50.

Comment: Where the y-axis hits the X-axis is basic chart formatting.  The link I posted shows how to have only X-axis labels above 30 show (those are formatted as black text, whereas 30 and below are white text, and so won't be visible assuming your chart background is also white)

Comment: Hmm, that's clever, thanks. It's not quite what I'm going for though. Can you check the question again? I've edited the question, and added images for what I'm going for.