# Custom x-axis on Excel chart

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

So I have a simple 5 year stock chart in Excel (10/19/2016 to 10/19/2021). Now the default setting has the x axis tick marks set on 10/19 of every year. If I change it to show the tick marks on January 1 of every year, then the first 10 months in the chart are blank since the data only starts on 10/19/2016.

So what I would like to do is have the first year in the chart (2016) start on 10/19 (where the data starts) and all remaining years to start on Jan 1. Is there a way to do this in vba? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I haven't tried any code so far tbh cause I don't know where to start. Seems like this should be easy to do but I couldn't find anything as to how to do it.

Comment: I found this question to be fairly similar to mine but it was never really answered:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855768/customizing-tick-marks-and-labels-on-x-axis-excel-vba

Comment: Unfortunately, the tick marks start at the first X value on the axis, and you can't have one tick mark length for the first part of the chart and different tick mark lengths for the rest. You could hide the default axis tick marks and tick labels and add a customer series along the axis, with a plus-sign marker every place you want a tick mark, and a data label located below each of these markers with the appropriate date.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I answered a similar question, [Customizing tick marks and labels on x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855768/customizing-tick-marks-and-labels-on-x-axis-excel-vba/69700194#69700194).

You need to hide the default axis and build your own. In my example, I want the axis to start at 30 and end at 730, but have tick marks and labels at 100, 200, 300, etc.

I set up a data range with X values in one column of 100, 200, 300, ... 700, and Y values of zero in the next column.

Chart 1 is the original chart without anything added or removed. Chart 2 has the added series, shown as orange plus-sign markers. Chart 3 has data labels below these added points, showing the default Y values of zero (orange text). In Chart 4 I have formatted the labels so that they show the X values instead of the Y values. In Chart 5 I have changed the X axis scale so it starts at 30 and ends at 730. I have also hidden the axis labels, not by removing them, but my using a custom number format of "  ", which preserves the margin below the axis to leave room for my custom data labels. Finally in Chart 6 I have formatted the plus sign markers to match the axis line and the data labels to match the other chart text. I have also formatted the Y axis with major tick marks that cross the axis.

[image]